# Function Questions Calculus 2

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined for all real numbers $x$, which satisfies:
      $$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) \qquad (a)$$
for all real numbers $x,y$.

1. Prove that the only constant functions satisfying $(a)$ are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1$. 
2.Prove that $f(0)=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.
3. Suppose $f(0)\neq 0$. Prove that $f(0)=1$.
4. Prove that $f(2)=(f(1))^2$ and $f(3) = (f(1))^3$.
5. Prove that $f(-1)=\frac{1}{f(1)}$.

Comment: I think part $4.$ needs more... are there two equations here?

Comment: Part 4 should be f(3)=(f(1))^3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose $f\equiv a$, then for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f(x+y)=a=f(x)f(y)=a^2$, or $a(a-1)=0$, which yields that $a=0$ or $a=1$.
2. By the condition that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all real numbers $x,y$, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ take $y=0$, and then we have $f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)\cdot f(0)=0$ since $f(0)=0$.
3. By the condition that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all real numbers $x,y$, take $x=y=0$, which gives us that $f(0)=f(0+0)=[f(0)]^2$, or $f(0)[f(0)-1]=0$. As $f(0)\ne 0$, it must be that $f(0)=1$.
4. $f(2)=f(1+1)=[f(1)]^2$;  $f(3)=f(2+1)=f(2)f(1)=[f(1)]^3$. (in general, $f(2)\ne [f(3)]^3$, you can try $f(x)=e^x$).
5. This is not true in general: if $f(x)\equiv 0$, then this property fails obviously. But if $f(0)\ne 0$, then it is true: by what we proved in 3, now we must have $1=f(0)$, and hence $1=f(0)=f(1+(-1))=f(1)f(-1)$, establishing the property.

Comment: Posting full solution instead of hints for that standard task: *cui bono*?

Comment: The answer for question 1 doesn't make sense to me. (a) was just denoting the equation in the given statement.